How to dump to pickle file for each iteration without saving in memory?
I have a python code which save dictionary to data array and dump data array to a pickle file.
This is original code.
with torch.no_grad():
   char_bboxes, char_scores, word_instances = charnet.find_charbox(im, scale_w, scale_h, original_w, original_h, word_boxes, os.path.splitext(im_name)[0])
   ALL, BOX, new_dict = save_word_recognition(ALL, BOX, word_instances, os.path.splitext(im_name)[0], args.results_dir, cfg.RESULTS_SEPARATOR, pointsList, transcriptionsList
                ,im_original, gaussianTransformer)
   if 'gt' in new_dict:
      data.append(new_dict)

with open('./data/roidb_'+ args.data_name+'.pik','wb') as f:
   pickle.dump(data,f)
   f.close()
print(ALL, BOX, BOX/ALL)
print(len(data))

Since I have a lot of data so memory is not enough.
How can I dump have same pickle file for each iteration?
The code is modified like below.
with torch.no_grad():
   char_bboxes, char_scores, word_instances = charnet.find_charbox(im, scale_w, scale_h, original_w, original_h, word_boxes, os.path.splitext(im_name)[0])
   ALL, BOX, new_dict = save_word_recognition(ALL, BOX, word_instances, os.path.splitext(im_name)[0], args.results_dir, cfg.RESULTS_SEPARATOR, pointsList, transcriptionsList
                ,im_original, gaussianTransformer)

  
   if 'gt' in new_dict:
       with open('./data/roidb_'+ args.data_name+'.pik','a+') as f:
           pickle.dump(new_dict,f)
           f.close()

I have error as below.
File "code/utils/find_char_box.py", line 183, in <module>
    pickle.dump(new_dict,f)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

How can I save to pickle without memory issue?

Why are you opening the file in a+ mode? 2 things... You can't append to a pickle file (well, you could but you'd corrupt it) and furthermore it needs to be opened in binary mode. Also, why are you calling f.close() when you're using a context manager?

@SIGHUP, why would appending to a pickle file corrupt it?  I can't see anything like that in docs, and it seems to work just fine for me.

@NikolajŠ. It won't work. If you'd like to have a chat session I'll be happy to demonstrate why it doesn't work

It does work just fine.

In your first attempt, you open file as binary one (which is what pickle needs).  Then in your "iterative" approach, you open file as text, hence the failure.
